# How to determine suitable server specifications

Tags: android, ios

I am working on store mobile application that communicates a remote server to retrieve the store contents, that includes images and texts, then displays them to public users. I want to specify the best specifications of the hosting server for this app, these includes:

- HardDisk Space
- Processor Cores
- Traffic Bandwidth
- RAM

I know that depends on how frequently the server is accessed and the number of access within specific period, but I have two questions:

1. How to predict the volume of server access?
2. Suppose that server access information is known, how to specify the server specifications depends on it? (eg: 1000 accesses on hour, RAM=xx)?

Thank you